# How to remove page_id from wordpress url

Tags: wordpress, url

I am using Wordpress 3.6

How to remove page_id or post name from site homepage?

Example: **www.mysite.com/?page_id=10** or **www.mysite.com/main**

I need this: **www.mysite.com**

Comment: Google is great - http://codex.wordpress.org/Using_Permalinks <- for pretty URLs and http://codex.wordpress.org/Creating_a_Static_Front_Page <- how to set a static front page

Comment: Finally i found where problem is. I have installed new wordpress site and without any plugins Homepage works well. BUT when i installed Polylang plugin homepage id always displayed in url, even if homepage is a static page.

Comment: ah now you see -> if you had said you had had it working previously I wouldn't have been quite so sarcastic with you :-P glad you sorted it!

Answer (score 3):

Login to Wordpress, select "Settings" from the left-sidebar menu, and then "Reading." From there, change the radio button from "Your Latest Posts" to "A Static Page." Select the page you want to use as your home from the dropdown menu, and select a corresponding page to represent your blog loop.

A more through information can be found here: http://codex.wordpress.org/Creating_a_Static_Front_Page

Answer (score 2):

Go to wordpress dashboard and under settings you will Permalinks then change it to post name and problem will be solved just like that.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).